# Optional parameter in java (can be null)

Tags: java

I have a function with a boolean parameter, but it could be null too.

If it's true or false, it makes a query with a "WHERE" clause. If it was null, the query has no "WHERE" clause, only the select clause.

How can I do that in Java ?

Comment: The best way would probably be to write two methods: one with the boolean parameter, and one without. But you can also use a java.lang.Boolean, which can be null. Or use an enum with three values, instead of a boolean.

Comment: Best option would be to create an `enum` that takes three values `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNSPECIFIED`. This means you can write typesafe, nullsafe code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Boolean` class

```
public String foo(Boolean addWhere){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
    if(addWhere != null){
        query += (addWhere? " WHERE true" : " WHERE false");
    }
    return query;
}
```

Call it as following,

```
String q = foo(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.lang.Boolean; this is the wrapper class for primitive boolean. The value can be null, Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE, but due to auto-unboxing you can also directly compare with true and false.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do so:

- Declaring two functions, one with a `boolean` parameter and one without a parameter.
- Declaring one function with an `Optional<Boolean>` parameter.
- Declaring one funktion with a `Boolean` parameter, where `null` is the unspecified case.